# Transactional email bounce tracking

Tags: extension, bounce

I've just spent the day trying to set up bounce processing, and have it working for civimail, but found out that it doesn't work for transactional emails? I tried installing [the transactional emails extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/transactional-emails) by unzipping it to my ext folder with the rest of my extensions, but it doesn't show up.
Has anyone had luck installing it? 
I'm on CiviCRM 4.7.27 on Joomla 3.8.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what fixed it, but I deleted my civi and browser caches, reinstalled the extension, and refreshed my view and transactional emails showed up and it works wonderfully, thanks Fuzion!

Comment: Glad to hear it. You may as well accept your own answer so SE thinks the site is being well used.

Comment: ps there will be a new release soon with some improvements to Subject field which was not being utilised in some scenarios

Comment: Thanks Fuzion indeed! The extension worked without any fuss.